# How to use my MacBook Pro to remotely access my PC running Ubuntu at home?

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, macbook-pro, remote-access, 16.10

I have a nice PC that I built over the summer, but now that school has started, I want to able to access that computer (where all of my file structures for assignments are located) from any where on campus using my MacBook Pro. Examples of what I will need to be able to do from my laptop, controlling the PC include, opening apps such as IDEs and web browsers, setting up VPNs **for the PC from my laptop**, and submitting assignments to my university's servers using my PC's terminal (I have simple commands to use to do this). I have a dual boot setup on my PC with Ubuntu and Windows 10 on separate drives, but my question is only relevant to my MacBook and Ubuntu, which is my preferred OS for doing computer science homework. What options do I have for remotely controlling the PC from my laptop? More specifically, I need to control an Ubuntu PC from a Mac laptop to do the tasks mentioned above.

Comment: In my experience, the very easiest way (though it's not open source or anything) is to use TeamViewer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Nick, [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/) is a great general purpose Remote Desktop application. I Also like [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en). Both of these solutions are available on most platforms including Mac and Ubuntu, and tend to be reliable.

Regarding your need to set up a VPN remotely, I've never attempted to do that personally. I would not expect a remote desktop application to smoothly transition from a regular connection to a VPN connection, but you likely shouldn't have trouble re-connecting after starting the VPN. I don't have much experience with VPN services though, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a Virtual Machine yet?

If not, consider that you may want to VM Ubuntu on your Mac for the specific programs and needs you stated. Alternately, you may wish to control one machine via the other.

Check this link: [VirtualBox manual: Remote Virtual Machines](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html)